# Having trouble centering CSS shape and text

Tags: css

I've placed the code in a jsfiddle with the css…

https://jsfiddle.net/8oafjzrm/1/

I have 4 circles which I want centered to its titles which also have labels that should be centered within the shape. I can't seem to get it to work as I want though. I tried to move the label within the circle to its own div but then that gets moved completely out of the way.  This is the html...

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="circles">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="circle-title">Total Users</div>
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                    <div class="circle-text">6</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="circle-title">Active Users</div>
                    <div class="circle">6</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="circle-title">Total Logged</div>
                    <div class="circle">2,497</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="circle-title">Overall</div>
                    <div class="circle">76%</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the css that I was trying which likely has more than what I need but I'm just trying to hack away at a solution...

```
.circle {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 100px;
}

.circle-text {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 7.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle:before {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}


.circle-title {
    color: #653487;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Check the https://jsfiddle.net/wfqs3ohj/






You need to add 

    .circle {
     margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 300px;
    }

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think it would be just two lines to fix

Comment: Hope you give a thumbsup!

Comment: I would but can't since it was marked as duplicate … sorry :(